# How can I specify platform-specific commands depending upon the Runner's OS?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a number of configurations that I test in my repository. Some of them are platform specific and I control those with tags.

```
linux_specific_build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - linux
  script:
    - rm -rf build
    - mkdir build
    - cd build
    - cmake ../src/. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release
    - make -j 4
```

That's fine because I know that this script will always run on one of the linux runners, but I also have Windows runners.

I can build in a cross-platform manner `cmake --build .` works passably, but it fails to make use of multiple cores. I actually run into more trouble with sanitizing the build directory. `rm -rf` does not exist in Windows ( the equivalent is `rmdir /s /q` ).

Is there a way in .gitlab-ci.yml to specify different scripts for the same job depending on tags or runner platform? I don't want or need ( in fact, I strongly prefer not ) to build every configuration on every platform.

Comment: You can just add another job with different tags/script sections for the same stage.